# Combining multiple subplots after they've been created, getting a new one, and replacing the old ones in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

The difficulty I am facing is that I already have a figure with several subplots, and I would like to combine certain subplots into a new one and set a new position for it.

Please see the pic below, as it shows that there are 4 subplots, I would like to, for example, combine 7/2 & 7/3 subplot, so I need to combine these 2 days' data and plot, which I've already done.

Then I want to replace 7/2 & 7/3 subplot with the new one. So the figure will contain 3 subplots, 7/1, 7/2, 7/4, the new 7/2 contains 7/2~7/3 data.

If I know the position of one subplot, I might able to replace it with a new one. I tried to google "how to use label to get subplot position", and a page shows that I can use  **ax.get_position()**, which I put it into def function and call it by using combine button, yet it shows error. It seems that I misunderstand it.

I've stuck in this situation for a while and still cannot find a solution for even getting the position of subplot. Not to mention to go on to the very next step, e.g. having a reset function to reset the combined-subplot into the original ones.

If someone knows how to do it, please leave your answer or even a clue. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import * 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, 
NavigationToolbar2Tk)

data = {
        "Date": ["2022-07-01"] * 500 + 
        ["2022-07-02"] * 500 + 
        ["2022-07-03"] * 500 + 
        ["2022-07-04"] * 500,
        "OB1": range(2501, 4501),
        "OB2": range(1, 2001)}

# set into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# get unique dates 
df['date_only'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
date_only = df['date_only'].dt.date
num_days = len(date_only.unique())

# multi-indexing
df = df.set_index(['Date'])

def getinfo():
    print(pos1 = ax.get_position())

# tkinter window setting
window = Tk()
window.title("Prototype")
window.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350)) 

# top_frame
top_frame = Frame(window) 
top_frame.grid(row = 0, sticky = "ew")
# center_frame 
center_frame = Frame(window, bg='gray')
center_frame.grid(row = 1, sticky = 'nesw')
# bottom_frame
bottom_frame = Frame(window, bg='silver')
bottom_frame.grid(row = 2, sticky='nesw')

# container setting 
window.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=7) 
window.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# starting date & entry
Label(top_frame, border=5, text ="start", width=6).grid(row=0, column=1) 
Entry(top_frame, bd=5, width=13).grid(row=0, column=2)
# end date & entry
Label(top_frame, border=5, text ="end", width=6).grid(row=0, column=3) 
Entry(top_frame, bd=5, width=13).grid(row=0, column=4)
# combine button
Button(top_frame, bd=3, text="combine", width=8,command = getinfo).grid(row=0, column=5)  
                  
# supblot loop
i = 1
fig, ax=plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=num_days, sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(right=1, left=0, hspace=0, wspace=0) 
for j, sub_df in df.groupby(level=0):
    plt.subplot(1, num_days, 0+i)
    plt.xlabel(j, fontsize=8) 
    x = sub_df['OB1']
    y = sub_df['OB2']
    plt.barh(x, y)
    plt.xticks([]) 
    plt.yticks([])
    i = i + 1 
    
# canvas 
canvas=FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=center_frame)
canvas.draw() 
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, 
                        fill=tk.BOTH, 
                        expand=tk.YES) 
                        
mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe, the package I developed (https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib) can help you.  
By using this package, you can re-arrange the subplot positions after creating them.

Comment: @Hideto，the package looks easy to use than other methods, I will try the package your provide and let you know if it works for my situation. Thank you very much.